# Core Plot: How do you centre the axis labels beneath bars / horizontally offset them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plot, label, core-plot

I am making a column chart in Core Plot, and I want the x-labels to appear beneath the columns, rather than on the left and right. Having trouble finding solutions through searches; either outdated or not related. Feel like plenty of people have had this problem before, I'm just using the wrong keywords.

Screenshot of how it looks right now:

[image: screenshot of current state]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bars are centered at the bar location returned from the datasource, plus or minus any `barOffset`. For a stacked plot like this, use the default `barOffset` of zero (0) and make sure the bar locations match the tick locations on the axis.

Comment: It looks like the axis tick locations are 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. Make sure the bar locations returned from the datasource are the same. Post your bar plot and axis setup code and the datasource methods if you're still having trouble.